# Bad results when retraining MobilnetSSD v1 TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, object-detection-api

I'd like to retrain ssd_mobilenet_v1_0.75_depth_coco from [Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) for a single class only (person).

I created TF records from COCO 2017 sets. This gives 64115 training examples and 2693 validation examples.

I set up a notebook on Google Colab that uses Object Detection API. Training works, but my results are really bad:

```
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.001
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.003
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.002
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.005
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.049
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.001
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.131
```

[image]

This is after I added to pipeline.config line **fine_tune_checkpoint_type: 'detection'** as explained [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3922), because TF logged that layers are missing.

The only changes in config are:

```
train_config {
   batch_size: 24
   num_steps: 500
   fine_tune_checkpoint_type: 'detection'
}
eval_config {
   num_examples: 2693
}
```

add paths of course.

I run model_main.py like this

```
!python object_detection/model_main.py \
   --pipeline_config_path="pipeline.config" \
   --model_dir="training/" \
   --alsologtostderr \
   --num_train_steps=500
```

I'll be running this model on more steps to handle entire dataset, but I think that 12k examples is enough for better results.
Any idea what is going on here?

**Full config**

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_mobilenet_v1"
      depth_multiplier: 0.75
      min_depth: 16
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 3.99999989895e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.0299999993294
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.97000002861
          center: true
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000475
          train: true
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 3.99999989895e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.00999999977648
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.97000002861
            center: true
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000475
            train: true
          }
        }
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.800000011921
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.59999990463
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.20000000298
        max_scale: 0.949999988079
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.333299994469
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.300000011921
        iou_threshold: 0.600000023842
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
          delta: 1.0
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 2.0
          alpha: 0.75
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 24
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.899999976158
          total_steps: 10000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.300000011921
          warmup_steps: 300
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.899999976158
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/content/ssd_mobilenet_v1_0.75_depth_300x300_coco14_sync_2018_07_03/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: 'detection'
  num_steps: 500
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/content/classes.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/content/gdrive/My Drive/coco_train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  num_examples: 2693
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "/content/classes.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/content/gdrive/My Drive/coco_val.record"
  }
}
```

**Plots**
[image]
[image]

**EDIT**
**After 27k/53k steps**

```
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.005
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.020
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.001
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.001
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.012
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.016
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.048
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.048
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.000
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.130
```

Basically it put one box with 51% probability on eval images (just one example here):

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is better to provide the complete config file to determine if some parameters are appropriate. Also it would be better to provide training loss and eval loss plots. In your example, it looks like the `non_max_suppression` threshold needs to be adjusted

Comment: I added config and plots. It seems that there was only 1 epoch.

Comment: The loss plot suggests that the model has not been well-trained. Although the dataset is large enough, more epochs are needed. Supposedly the model is OK when the loss goes below 1.

Comment: Yeah ok, but which object should get num_epochs field?

Comment: There is no `num_epochs` field, just `num_steps` in `train_config`. The number of epochs is decided by the number of steps and batch size.

Comment: OK, I'll increase steps to let's say 50k and give back feedback. Will evaluation start after each epoch or I should add something in config?

Comment: The evaluation will start after each checkpoint is saved. Typically this is 10-15 minutes by default config.

Comment: And what about this warnings?

WARNING:tensorflow:Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
WARNING:tensorflow:Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0. Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.

Comment: i'm not sure but when i train i got this too